# Adding Facebook iPhone SDK to Project = 102 error and build failed

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

As far as I can tell I've followed [the instructions](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_iPhone_SDK) perfectly ... and yet I am getting 102 errors and build failed when I attempt to build my iPhone application project in XCode.

I'm using XCode 3.2.2.

What am I missing?

This is driving me mad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by doing the following:

1. Double-click the application name under "Targets"
2. Click on "Build"
3. Under "Header Search Paths" add .. ../../Frameworks/fbconnect-iphone/src

You have to work from the TARGET rather than Project > Project Settings.

How come this DOES NOT WORK when, per the instructions, I set the "Header Search Paths" information via "Project > Project Settings"?